# How import large sql file (108MB) in server mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **108MB SQL** file, how can i import this file in server using **PHP Script**?

I try to do this, but no result

```
mysql -h 213.xyz.200.xx -u myUsername -p MyPassword MyDatabase < temporarytable.sql
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: It make take some time to import that data. What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` say is happening?

Comment: I dn't get any error , and also its a small size of database file, temporarytable.sql is just 2KB

Comment: Don't do it in PHP. Do it directly on command line. Remove the space between `-pMyPassword` if you're getting an auth error. If you're not getting any errors but it just looks like it's waiting, then yes you need to wait: It will take some time to import a 108MB dump.

Comment: @m3shabeer if you just leave out MyPassword, it will prompt you for the password. What behavior do you get? If it just sits there and does nothing, your server may not allow mysql connections from remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

Take the space out after the `-p` or don't put the password in at all and it will prompt you for it.

```
mysql -h 213.xyz.200.xx -u myUsername -pMyPassword MyDatabase < temporarytable.sql
```